# What's the best way to set up symbolic links to current installs, e.g python -> python2.6

Tags: python, macos, macports

What's the best way to set up symbolic links to current installs, e.g python -> python2.6?

I've just installed python2.6 through Macports at /opt/local/bin/python2.6, I'd now like to set up a symbolic link called python here /usr/local/bin/.  I then want to be able to add this line at the beginning of my pythons scripts so it knows where to look: #!/usr/local/bin/python.  But what happens when I upgrade python to python2.7 for example, do I just need to remember to go to my symbolic link and change it?  I guess I'll remember because it likely won't work anymore?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, MacPorts deliberately and carefully installs everything into a separate directory space: `/opt/local`.  This ensures it does not conflict with anything installed as part of OS X or third-parties.  To ensure that MacPorts-installed executables are found first, the recommended solution is to modify your shell `PATH` to put `/opt/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

MacPorts also provides a special port package, [python_select](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=python_select), to manage which python version is pointed to by the command `python` in `/opt/local/bin`.

```
sudo port install python_select
sudo python_select
```

Then, to make your scripts use your current preferred python, the traditional solution is to use the [`env` program in the shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env) of your scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 2):

Symlink the version you use most.

When you need another version, run it by specifying the version number, e.g.:

```
$ python2.5 dev_appserver.py myapp
```

Answer (score -3):

Not sure about OSX, here is what I do on Ubuntu 9.04:

```
>which python
#/usr/bin/python
```

Just replace that file with a sym link to the version of Python you actually want to use:

```
>sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6/python /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: No, you should *not* do this!  /usr/bin/python is the Apple-supplied python.  It's part of OS X: at worst, you risk breaking your system by doing that; at best, it will get overwritten by a future OS X update.